# Graphic card from Nvidia to Intel In Ubuntu12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

Recently I change My mainboard and my graphic card also change, from Nvidia to Intel, both integrate.

But I don't know how to do with my graphic driver.

I try to install Intel graphic driver from [this](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads). But it seems not support `12.04` no longer.

How to switch to native driver in `12.04`?

Or another advise ?

This is my graphic card's info:

```
xsuii@xsuii-Unknow:~$ sudo lshw -c display
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Thanks a lot if you can help me.

Comment: My Fedora laptop has the same intergrated graphics - lshw outputs: `[wilf@comp ~]$ sudo lshw -c display 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
...
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom`
       **configuration: driver=i915 latency=0**
       `resources: irq:41 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)`

Comment: lspci also says `Kernel driver in use: i915` - they were automatically installed, so I do not know how to configure the drivers as such - but try searching for `modprobe`

Answer (score 0):

Intel graphic card support is built in into Ubuntu 12.04, you don't need to install a driver separately. If you are looking for latest Intel drivers consider adding PPA by Glassen https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver

Comment: That means I'm using a built-in Intel driver? If not and it support by Ubuntu 12.04, I would like to know how to use it. Thanks. `PPA` may be my secondary concideration.